# Split() fails generating java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError . How to remove this error?

Tags: java, eclipse

i am doing splitting on one line of a text file,however i am getting error
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at String[] num= firstline.split(","); line.Can anyone please tell where am i wrong

```
public class split {
    private static java.io.File file;
    private static BufferedReader reader;
    static int  noOfLines=0;
    
    static {
        try {
            file = new java.io.File("/home/madhu95/Desktop/data.txt");
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(String.valueOf(file)));
            while (reader.readLine() != null) {
                noOfLines++;
            }
            System.out.println(noOfLines);
            String firstline=reader.readLine();
            String[] num= firstline.split(",");
            int numberofmobile=Integer.parseInt(num[0]);
            System.out.println(numberofmobile);
            int numberofDept=Integer.parseInt(num[1]);
            
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
  
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: Your while loop has already read through the file to the end which is null. Should be: `String firstLine; while ((firstLine = reader.readLine()) != null) { noOfLines++; if (numOfLines == 1 && !firstLine.trim().isEmpty()) { String[] num= firstline.split(","); } }`

Comment: i wan to read the lines in different methods after counting the number of lines,so how to do that?

Comment: What other methods...you don't show the code following that scheme. Depends on how much data is in the file. Read each line into a List interface of Mobile (`List<Mobile>`) if it's not too big. Of course you should create a class for creating instances of Mobile.

Comment: ``firstLine`` is null. Once your reader has read all the lines (in your while loop), readLine() will return null.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> while (reader.readLine() != null) {
>        noOfLines++;
> }
> ```

This consumes the stream. After this loop is done, you're at the end of the file.

> `String firstline=reader.readLine();`

So this is a lie then - it's not the first line. Not anymore. By counting lines, you are no longer there. In fact, `firstline` is always going to be `null` here.

> `String[] num= firstline.split(",");`

`.` where the thing to the left of it is `null`, gets you an NPE. You don't catch that, so, your initialization fails. Don't catch that exception - fix the problem where you've forwarded through the entire file by counting lines.

---

EDIT: Adding a solution that most likely solves all your problems.

Given that you want to know the # of lines before you process them, you'd either need to read the file twice or completely rewrite your logic to no longer need to know # of lines in advance. Complicated, so, instead, what if you don't process the file, but you process a `List<String>` - which knows how many lines it has (`list.size()` will get you that information). Then, first read the file into a list of lines, and then take it from there:

```
import java.nio.file.*;

List<String> lines =
 Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/Path/to/your/data.txt"));
// ....
```

Comment: ok suppose i want to read these lines after counting then how to do that?

Comment: Either make another reader, or, (and this is better), count as you process. Also note that you can't open files this way (it leaks memory) - search the web for 'java try with resources' for an example of how to do it right.

Comment: i want to make use of this count in further reads. like lets count is 10 i want to execute 1 for loop for 1st 5 reads and another for loop for 2nd 5reads. can you give some idea how to write for this scenario?

Comment: Then your only option is to either read that file twice (open it in a try-with-resources block and count lines. Let the try-with-resources end. Then open it again, and pray nobody changed that file in between). That, or, open it once, 'cache' all lines into an arraylist, and then process that. This is the right answer if the input file contains fewer than 50,000 lines. I have added how to do that to this answer in an edit.